# Silverlight Validation - Optional Fields

Tags: silverlight, validation

Has any one used data validation on fields that are optional (nullable types)?

I.e. the field can be empty, but if data is entered, it must be valid?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can create a custom validator to validate the object

Comment: Sounds like a good option, do you know of any good online examples that demonstrate this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do add on the validation scenario (e.g. [StringLength(255)] but just not put a [required] attribute on it?